# Jenkins: stops execution of job abruptly

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scheduled pipeline which runs daily.
There was an error that I faced yesterday.One of my jobs in the pipeline failed abruptly.The console log didn't return any FAILURE status.But strangely the pipeline shows as SUCCESSFUL,despite the job failing.
My job uses chef to download files from object storage location.I checked the logs it is successful.But still somehow the job failed/interrupted.

One more thing I noticed is that though the job ran fully it still shows completed in 0ms
`Started 23 hr ago
Took 0 ms`

Below is the jenkins log at the time when the job started:

```
`    **Nov 28, 2017 1:47:10 PM hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserReader readLogPart
INFO: Start reading log part 0 in thread #0
Nov 28, 2017 1:47:10 PM hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserReader readLogPart
INFO: Done reading log part 0
Nov 28, 2017 1:47:11 PM hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserThread getLineStatuses
INFO: LogParserThread: Start parsing log part 0
Nov 28, 2017 1:47:11 PM hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserThread getLineStatuses
INFO: LogParserThread: Done parsing log part 0
Nov 28, 2017 1:47:11 PM hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserParser parseLogBody
INFO: LogParserParser: Parsing took 0 minutes (0) seconds.
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:08 PM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:08 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @858ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:09 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: Scavenging every 660000ms
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: SystemProperties.getProperty("JENKINS_HOME")
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:11 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@d23e042{/,file:///var/cache/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:11 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@13d73f29{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{127.0.0.1:8081}
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:11 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @3487ms
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:11 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:12 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:13 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:18 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:18 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:19 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component org.biouno.unochoice.model.ScriptlerScript$DescriptorImpl; skipping
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:19 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM jenkins.model.RunIdMigrator migrate
INFO: Migrating build records in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/build_spark_repo/builds
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM jenkins.model.RunIdMigrator doMigrate
WARNING: found unexpected dir lastSuccessfulBuild
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM jenkins.model.RunIdMigrator doMigrate
WARNING: found unexpected dir lastStableBuild
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM jenkins.model.RunIdMigrator migrate
WARNING: Build record migration (https://jenkins.io/redirect/build-record-migration) is one-way. If you need to downgrade Jenkins, run: java -classpath "/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.73.2.jar:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/stapler-1.250.jar:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/ant-1.8.4.jar:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar" jenkins.model.RunIdMigrator "/var/lib/jenkins"
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:20 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@479f04e6: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Nov 28 14:17:21 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@479f04e6]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5eedf60f
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5eedf60f: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@4a772b39: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Nov 28 14:17:21 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@4a772b39]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5e76549c
Nov 28, 2017 2:17:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5e76549c: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy**`
```

This worked after I re-run the job.

Just wanted to know what could be the cause of the error?